# Suppressing "welcome" message in mpg123?

Tags: application, stderr

I'm writing a node.js app that calls mpg123 to play audio at specified times. I'm keeping logs when this happens, but only when an error occurs (e.g. file not found errors).

When shelling out to mpg123 fails, my app captures the error, but also captures the standard `High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3 ...` message along with the actual error.

Short of grabbing the last line(s) of the output and only logging that, is there a way I can force mpg123 to suppress its welcome message and just show the error? The man page shows nothing that I can see, but I'm curious about other methods I haven't considered yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type `mpg123` without any filename and a list of options will be presented, including `-q`, which means *quiet*

eg normal output might look something like:

```
% mpg321 mysong.mp3
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layer 1, 2, and 3.
Version 0.3.2-1 (2012/03/25). Written and copyrights by Joe Drew,
now maintained by Nanakos Chrysostomos and others.
```

But with the `-q` flag it is silent.

Error message still appear:

```
% mpg123 -q nosuchsong.mp3
nosuchsong.mp3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That seems to be the answer on Unix. On Windows, it doesn't behave the same way, showing no errors, just the TODO messages present in that version. Guess it's a software bug then. I'll get reportin'. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, this _is_ Unix+Linux :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-q` option (`--quiet`); it suppresses diagnostic messages and the banner. You'll still get error messages.

Comment: Thanks for that. See my comment below. It looks like the Windows and Unix versions are different in their behaviour (the app is built to be cross-platform, hence why I asked here, as mpg123 is pretty common on Linux), so I'll report it to the developer and see what becomes of it. Thanks again :)