# How to suppress the welcome message in mpg123, but keep the songs?

Tags: bash

I've been wracking my head around this for a while.

- This answer: [Suppressing "welcome" message in mpg123?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306418/suppressing-welcome-message-in-mpg123) only answers the case when one wants to suppress all output
- This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797724/cannot-capture-diagnostic-output-from-mpg123-while-the-program-is-running leads me to think that the solution of redirecting output to a file and then reading that file wouldn't work
- Obvious things, like piping to sed, awk or tail to remove the first few lines don't work (e.g., using answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542425/bash-how-to-remove-first-2-lines-from-output)

Comment: `mpg123 tunes/* 2>&1 | tail -n +6` ?

Comment: Would you mind to explain _how_ the "obvious things" don't work for this particular case?

Comment: They corrupt the output, such that when closing the program, it prints an additional line to the beginning of the input, which I find very annoying.

Comment: In any case, since the program is open source I tried to recompile it without the welcome message, but that led to me completely messing up my installation, so I can't really test the above message right now.

Comment: Wow, I haven't used mpg123 since probably around 1999 or 2000.

Comment: Yeah, it died for a while, but then it got revived in 2008 or so. It briefly had competition from mpg321 because of GPL issues, but then solved those. I then found it last year because it was recommended by https://suckless.org/rocks/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that pipe buffering was causing problems with mpg123's `-C` option. This can be solved by using the `--line-buffered` option in grep, or `-u` in sed.

In the end, the set of flags I ended up using was:

`mpg123 -Z -C --title */* 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Ev "High Performance|written and copyright by|without any warranty but with best wishes|Terminal control enabled|MPEG 1.0|Decoding of" | sed -uE 's/Playing MPEG stream [0-9]+ of [0-9]+: //' | sed -uE "s/Directory: //" | sed -uE "s/\.\.\.//" |  sed -uE '/^\s*$/d'`

I'm going through the options step by step. Some of them answer the broader question of having a convenient mpg123 setup.

- `-Z` is eternal random shuffle
- `-C` allows for control commands
- `--title` changes the terminal's title to the title of the current song
- `*/*` looks for files in current subdirectories. If the files are in a given directory, '*' would suffice.
- `2>&1` redirects from standard error (to which mpg123 prints) to standard output, which can be manipulated using pipes
- `--line-buffered` in grep and the `-u` flag on sed avoid buffering, which was what was causing me problems.
- Other flags are just regex toggles and non-central to the question.

I then aliased this command for ease of use.
`alias pmr="clear; mpg123 -Z -C --title */* 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Ev 'High Performance|written and copyright by|without any warranty but with best wishes|Terminal control enabled|MPEG 1.0|Decoding of' | sed -uE 's/Playing MPEG stream [0-9]+ of [0-9]+: //' | sed -uE 's/Directory: //' | sed -uE 's/\.\.\.//' |  sed -uE '/^\s*$/d'" ## pmr := play music recursively`

tail has `-f` as a flag to avoid buffering, but it kept giving me problems.